# PIR Triggering for no reason

Tags: python, camera, sensor

I have a setup with a Raspberry PI model 3 a PIR sensor and a OEM HDTV Pi IR-Camera with two LED modules (pictures below).

I'm running a little Python script triggering a camera recording whenever the PIR sensor is detecting motion.

Now, the problem is that the sensor is detecting a lot of false positive motions. It seems to just trigger about every 30 seconds. I have tested the setup with two different PIR sensor but the issue remains.

I found out that the sensor seems to work ok as long as the camera is not being connected. Somehow the camera seems to interfere with the PIR sensor.

I'm no electronics expert so I'm kind of stuck and don't know what to do. Any help from you guys is highly appreciated.

Here's my Python script and some pictures of my setup:

```
from gpiozero import MotionSensor
from picamera import PiCamera
from datetime import datetime

sensor = MotionSensor(4)
camera = PiCamera()

while True:
    sensor.wait_for_motion()
    print("I can see you!")
    filename = "Intruder_{0:%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S}.h264".format(datetime.now())
    camera.start_recording(filename)

    sensor.wait_for_no_motion()
    print("I don't see any motion")
    camera.stop_recording()
```

[image: GPIO]
[image: PIR sensor wiring]
[image: PIR sensor settings]
[image: Complete setup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce the sensitivity of the PIR sensor by turning the little yellow trimpot ("Phillips screw") anti-clockwise. On your [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoNRY.jpg) it is the top one.

This [adafruit overview](https://learn.adafruit.com/pir-passive-infrared-proximity-motion-sensor) could be helpful.

Make sure that no unwanted infrared transmitter triggers the PIR sensor, like LEDs or (television) remote control unit.

Regarding your python script: I would add `camera.close()` in a new line after `camera.stop_recording()`. And `KeyboardInterrupt` to stop the running script from command line by pressing `ctrl+c`:

```
from gpiozero import MotionSensor
from picamera import PiCamera
from datetime import datetime

sensor = MotionSensor(4)
camera = PiCamera()

while True:
    sensor.wait_for_motion()
    print("I can see you!")
    filename = "Intruder_{0:%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S}.h264".format(datetime.now())
    camera.start_recording(filename)

    sensor.wait_for_no_motion()
    print("I don't see any motion")
    camera.stop_recording()
    camera.close()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        camera.close()
        exit()
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't resolve the problem. It's still triggering about every minute. Any other ideas?

Comment: "every 30 seconds" and now "every minute" - sounds like the trimpot has an effect. Have you terminated the script, added `camera.close()`, screw the trimpot a little bit, started the script and then checked the result or without stop/start?

Comment: You're right. But the interference seems to be the problem. I.e. when the PIR measures it seems to be influence by the camera.

Comment: I would disconnect the two LEDs beside the camera, reboot and test again

Comment: Yes, I think that should do the trick. I've found out that the PIR is triggering when the IR LEDs are pointing into the same direction. So, I guess that's the problem. I try disconnecting them and report back...

Comment: @Favian Ok, it was definitely the two IR LEDs screwing with the IR sensor. I removed both LEDs from the camera and voila. Everything working perfectly!

Comment: @tk78 glad to hear, answer edited to reflect this

Comment: FYI: There was still another issue. Either WiFi or Bluetoot causes some fluctuation in power supply. Turned both off and the issue never occured again.

Answer (score 1):

to help others with the triggerless PIR responses i can tell about my experiences:
I have my Pi with PiCamera near the Front door, and outside is my PIR activated light. 
The Pi runs mjpeg-streamer constantly. When I start the app on my smartphone to view it, the Light switches on.
Since I don't have ethernetwires near the front door, I used a Devolo Powerline Adapter set. 
When I started to send loads of data THAT triggered the PIR sensor. 
So, maybe you recognize yourself in this setup, or maybe you have another 'old' peace of electronics nearby? maybe the Pi power adapter is noisy? 
 PIR sersors work on fairly low voltage and is (therefore) relatively sensitive for external noise as well.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the problem is noise on the PIR power line triggering the PIR. This can be caused by virtually any other device, even the MCU doing something. I have the same problem caused by the MCU going into sleep mode. Some suggest filters on the power line, some get away with delaying re-arming of the PIR until nothing else is happening which could cause a teeny spike. The latter is working so far for me.